# Galois theory of periods of algebraic varieties PhD project

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, transcendental-number-theory, periods

I finished my MMath at Exeter in July of this year and I would like to undertake a PhD at the interface of algebraic geometry, number theory and Galois theory. More specifically, I recently came across Yves André's paper 'Galois theory, motives and transcendental numbers' in which he predicts that there ought to exist a Galois theory for some transcendental numbers that are somehow defined by the periods of algebraic varieties. This, in particular, is the research topic that I would like to work towards via a PhD. However, with the exception of Francis Brown at Oxford (who, alas, has informed me that he is not currently seeking any new PhD students), there does not seem to be anybody working on this topic in the UK. So, my question is this:

Are there any other experts on this topic $-$ or related topics $-$ in the UK whom I can enquire with regarding a PhD project?

EDIT: Any reading list recommendations would also be very much appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Wanting to stay in the UK will greatly limit your options. You should look into the possibility of doing your PhD abroad too.

Comment: @user347489 I would certainly be willing to travel to another country. However, the biggest barrier to studying abroad is funding. Are you aware of any institutions abroad that would consider funding PhD students from the UK and which have staff who specialise in the aforementioned topic?

Comment: Not specifically, but I know that there are a variety of sources of funding, starting with grants that researchers have. You should make a list of possible programs and people you're interested in, then contact said person **and** the coordinator of graduate studies. The reason for this is that very often professors are very busy and might not respond to your email, but that doesn't mean they're not looking for students. Chances are at least one of them will know what are the possible avenues to get you there.

Comment: @user347489 Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: @Sazed: Pretty much any research university in the US (and Canada) provides their Ph.D. students in mathematics with a funded TA position.  So funding is not a problem.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov TA salaries are hardly enough to make a living in many university towns/cities. Other source of funding is often required, but this is where the OP needs to look for options.

Comment: @user347489: Your comment does not make sense.  Thousands of Ph.D. students successfully complete their Ph.D. degrees every year, while receiving a salary that according to you is "hardly enough to make a living" (whatever that means).  The typical salary is not conducive to a luxury lifestyle, but is perfectly sufficient for a Ph.D. student, unless you have dependents to support.